# How to correctly make a POST request to a form login and get the session-token?

Tags: http, cookies, web-crawler, elixir

I'm building a web crawler to scrape an web page information that are behind a authentication login form. So I need to login in the app with a bare `HTTP` request first to be able to scrape needed info.

As I know, the script need to send a `POST` request with login params urlencoded in addition with the `csrf-token` and also a unauthenticated `session-cookie` as a cookie header, right?

The app that I'm trying to scrape is: https://app-sandbox.kobana.com.br

Taking a look on `GET` request headers/body of the login page I got:

- a `meta` tag with name `csrf-param` with content set to `authenticity_token`
- a `meta` tag with name `csrf-token` and it's content
- a hidden `input` tag with name `authenticity_token` and it's content
- a unauthenticated `session-token` that can be retrieved from `set-cookie` header

When I do a `POST` request on browser, what is sent is this `authenticity_token` and a `cookie` header with multiples cookies values that I can't find in any request/response header.

So I tried to reproduce this login flow with `cURL` and after of send correct body/headers I receive a `302` response, which is ok. But following the redirect link I get a `not_found 404` response.

I also tried to follow this flow with `insomnia/postman` but in this case I have a success login.

My actual code to retrieve the authenticated `session-token` is:

```
defmodule KobanaBrowserClient do
  defp base_url, do: "https://app-sandbox.kobana.com.br"
  defp sign_in_path, do: base_url() <> "/users/sign_in"

  def sign_in(body, cookie) do
    HttpClient.post(build_client(), sign_in_path(), body, headers: [{"cookie", cookie}])
  end

  def get_session_cookie(email, password) do
    {:ok, response} = get_sign_in_page()

    # Extrai o cookie não autenticado a partir do Headers
    cookie = parse_session_cookie(response.headers)

    {:ok, document} = Floki.parse_document(response.body)

    # Extrai o token CSRF do body da requisição
    authenticity_token =
      document
      |> Floki.find(~s(form input[name="authenticity_token"]))
      |> Floki.attribute("value")
      |> Floki.text()

    req_body = %{
      "user[email]" => email,
      "user[password]" => password,
      "user[remember_me]" => 0,
      "authenticity_token" => authenticity_token
    }

    {:ok, login_response} = sign_in(req_body, cookie)

    parse_session_cookie(login_response.headers)
  end

  def parse_session_cookie(headers) do
    headers
    |> Enum.reduce("", fn
      {"set-cookie", cookie}, acc -> acc <> " " <> cookie
      _, acc -> acc
    end)
    |> String.trim()
  end
end
```

And the `cURL` command generated by `insomnia` is:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url https://app-sandbox.kobana.com.br/users/sign_in \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --cookie '_boletosimples_session=eaI6y7pJ1%252BHj0CyC3%252BgWE%252FCEYV4K5mFoYANYKXCasH1LvhrmShvZUGdeYJQo3QCSXC%252FTU9s4V77Csc82FsOhX8bJz%252F%252BVRSvMKFa2I%252BHV4Nu5OeeIA9fXzooRSljtik9SvKD3of1dVY68EZXe67mXberh2i0P1eemc2ixS0Zp%252FWhaxQr7o1BOKJVL6EARV2uUL7hfwWg58z%252BHmkAZ2eGpHwrWESOuR7ALc8X%252Fk5l35RVeKIsbbcduxFqsQlh4olBJ8gxYNQVZXPy1p1VTvrMN8yGhlPGbFxzCJG4hScYMneB0Ph4%252Ba5HFA0F84hd%252FOeiWjCPTkeDDNcajHgaH8YI6grWRfS42AEziRLK6VnQuZtROue%252FNIgn%252BeCqwofW%252BdMrpbvppbc19uEWxhDCrzvit0Cc7aE1LltUzlAWJmIlrNXxUJlN7JM%252FJGL6AoMe4iYyj7%252BbRasuQ%252B9WQRycVYK%252Bxe40ZG6DqjY7wolBxw%252FC6mAoWpHyYv696UUoV1uFQahK%252BbOad8nQ9Myhvj3iFPaV3isqMMdlTWaQIEjOkgLT13dXVUxSLcrT62VtZC%252Fa5jSo31%252FDxmFfEQZv0zlW8e3eJ%252BpgPeUWBWRc%252BUMiJDMPQ1sDknka2w4gMAGRna0B7IoIxG38vkFwAQ3Ob8wPn6t4SU%252FfgZkCjmjggxs87GNXyaZjHqVyYjIr4IIODiwd9kRo1FATu%252Bms516lhNi3aF1wFqZyWS46yMlq0ZlUDSFXFI73U1ggswN2DIeOmFGBiw6ZoW%252B8CEWrZ0QOHXAyyMVGI8FL1FtaHnBp0prmvW88I--FAwVzHnQF%252BJg4NJ0--uTpgEAZoQEQdp%252BBHaJMU%252BQ%253D%253D; user.id=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6Ik1qZzJOZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJjb29raWUudXNlci5pZCJ9fQ%253D%253D--4b3f7664fa367f606bcddead8e20c13202cb8415; user.expires_at=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IklqSXdNakl0TURNdE1UUlVNVGM2TlRVNk5ETXRNRE02TURBaSIsImV4cCI6bnVsbCwicHVyIjoiY29va2llLnVzZXIuZXhwaXJlc19hdCJ9fQ%253D%253D--5f3bcd28b81d798b5270421b5f4d610b4ec200a1; user_email=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkluWnBkRzl5TG14bFlXeEFjMjlzWm1GamFXd3VZMjl0TG1KeUlnPT0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImNvb2tpZS51c2VyX2VtYWlsIn19--0e04fcebc5f9ce0acdbe7e92d55c19f28ab37121; user_tracking_uid=eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IklqazJaVFUzTVRBeExUbGxOVEl0WlRFME55MW1NMlJsTFRjNFl6SmtNREF4TVRFeE1pST0iLCJleHAiOm51bGwsInB1ciI6ImNvb2tpZS51c2VyX3RyYWNraW5nX3VpZCJ9fQ%253D%253D--ee68c7d2dc9f463a4689769a1c4608158ce41463; boletosimples_visitor_guid=96e57101-9e52-e147-f3de-78c2d0011112' \
  --data authenticity_token=Dj-_4TVjbSwmDjjorQvI37wMWy5pHmcrVSlkp2EkpojorZiP2a3_AxWiZ47Rkdh3pvoY55j1EIH4z-ze5qUYMg \
  --data 'user[email]=account_email' \
  --data 'user[password]=account_pass' \
  --data 'user[remember_me]=0'
```

Which fails with a `404` resopnse. What can be happening?

Comment: This question would be more focused if you asked specifically about how to make the HTTP request using a specific Elixir HTTP client, e.g. `HTTPoison`. Also, be aware that some login forms may have tokens that expire, which means that your tests using `cURL` or `Insomnia` might fail because the token has expired during the time it you to copy it.

Comment: But my problem isn't how to make HTTP requests with Elixir libs. I added elixir tag because my source code is in elixir so people can get a better context. Token expiracy time is a good point, but with some other tests I noted that even receiving a 404 response, the `session-token` returned on headers is authenticated and allows me to make authenticated requests, which is strange. For now I wan to understand why the server returns 404.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix, but one suggestion is to send all the headers that you see. The browser may be your best friend. Send the form (using a private window) and see the headers the browser is sending. I would send all the headers and removing one by one until it stop working.

Comment: This seems very specific to the website and how they have everything set up. I don't think this question is answerable as-is.